# lua.vm.js innerHTML error

Tags: javascript, lua, emscripten

I got the following lua.vm.js code:

```
local data=tostring(js.global.Module.read('/statsWidget.lcgi'))
print(data)
print(js.global.document.getElementById('statsWidget').innerHTML)
js.global.document.getElementById('statsWidget').innerHTML=data
```

while the ajax call and both prints work fine, trying to set innerHTML raises a javascript error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier lua.vm.js:5717
  _emscripten_run_script_int                lua.vm.js:5717
  iS                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  eX                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  iM                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  eZ                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  iD                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  iM                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  eZ                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  dB                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  k1                                        lua.vm.js:6407
  invoke_vii                                lua.vm.js:6359
  eS                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  e2                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  dA                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  cD                                        lua.vm.js:6406
  ccallFunc                                 lua.vm.js:536
  ccall                                     lua.vm.js:495
  Lua.execute                               lua.vm.js:6608
  (anonymous function)                      lua.vm.js:6614
  Lua.executeScripts                        lua.vm.js:6613
  window.onload                             lua.vm.js:6603
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's valid Lua syntax. It may be a bug in `lua.vm.js`'s parser.

Comment: i know it's valid Lua, what's strange is that there seems to be a JS syntax error in some code generated by lua.vm.js or emscripten (the line in `_emscripten_run_script_int` does an eval)

Comment: Well, `lua.vm.js` is a javascript library. It can call its own functions, which are recorded in the traceback when it throws an error.

Comment: @nonchip You will probably have more success finding a solution here: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't validate your data but for me this works:

```
-- working
js.global.document:getElementById('statsWidget').innerHTML= "foo"
```

While this fails:

```
-- not working
js.global.document.getElementById('statsWidget').innerHTML= "foo"
```

Notice the colon after the document. It adds an hidden self parameter to the function:

```
-- working too
js.global.document.getElementById(js.global.document,'statsWidget').innerHTML= "foo"
```

Comment: about the "however not working": you didn't define `self`. should be `js.global.document.getElementById(js.global.document, ...)`

Comment: except that i'm not a dude :P